# How to update old documents after adding new fields to the schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nosql, sql-update, mongoose-schema

let's say I have a `user` schema that looks like this:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

And then some people signed up in the website and `user` documents were created.

Then at some point in the future I added these additional fields to the `user` schema:

```
    joinedAt: {
        type: Data,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    about: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
```

What should I do to update old data? I come from `django` and in `django` I just run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and it will apply the changes to all existing data if it wasn't required or had a default value (Like `joinedAt` in this case).

But if it didn't (Like `about` field in this case) then it will ask me what should be the value for existing fields.

How is it done in Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a MongoDb update query like this:

```js
let about = "Whatever you want";

db.users.updateMany(
    {
        joinedAt: { $exists: false },
        about: { $exists: false },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            joinedAt: new Date(),
            about: about
        }
    }
);
```

OR

If you want a Node.js script then:

**STEP 1**: Create a file `user_migration.js`:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const DB_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB";

const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true
};

MongoClient.connect(DB_URI, options, (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR: Failed to connect to database.");
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  let dbName = DB_URI.split("/", -1).pop();
  let db = client.db(dbName);

  console.log(`Connected to ${dbName} database successfully.`);

  let about = "Whatever you want";
  db
    .collection('users')
    .updateMany(
      {
        joinedAt: { $exists: false },
        about: { $exists: false },
      },
      {
        $set: {
          joinedAt: new Date(),
          about: about
        }
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      // console.log(res);
      console.log(`${res.result.nModified} documents updated successfully.`);
      console.log("Database connection closed.");
      client.close();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      console.log("Database connection closed.");
      client.close();
    });
});
```

**STEP 2**: Run the file from the terminal:

```
node C:path\to\your\source_code\user_migration.js
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but is there a specific location to put the first solution code in? And should I keep it in my server code forever or it's one time only?

Comment: First solution is more like a one time script. So need to save it. If your application is in production then put the second solution in a folder named `migration_scripts` for example at root level (i.e., next to `index.js`/`package.json`) and preserve it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, glad this helped me. Thanks!

```
db.collection.updateMany()
```

Docs:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-update-many-method-update-document